# Discord Bot sends text file line by line

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a discord command, that writes the whole text file into the chat line by line, and I tried making it but somewhy It doesn't work properly.

```
    file = open('story.txt', 'r')

    @client.command(alisases = ['readfile'])
     async def story(ctx):
        for x in file:
            await ctx.send(file)
```

It runs, but only writes these lines:

[image: Picture]

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='story.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1250'>

Comment: You're sending the string representation of the file object. Did you mean `ctx.send(x)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the string representation of the file object rather than the lines in it.

You could do something like this:

```
@client.command(alisases = ['readfile'])
async def story(ctx):
    with open('story.txt', 'r') as story_file:
        for line in story_file:
            await ctx.send(line)
```

Also, it's a good practice to use the `with open` syntax as it assures that the file is being closed properly.

Comment: Although I have one more question if you don't mind. How can I time these messages? Because it writes it way too fast.

Comment: You can add a ```time.sleep(<amount of seconds>)``` at the end of every iteration

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep`, it's blocking (not good with `async`). Use `await asyncio.sleep` instead

Comment: @Benjin: I agree with you.

Comment: @y_os: After `await ctx.send(line)` you can add another line like `await asyncio.sleep(seconds)`. PS: Don't forget to import asyncio :D

Comment: Yes, asyncio.sleep worked for me. Thanks for the quick answers :)